# SQL-SERVER: JSON_MODIFY on json column with "contains" field match

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nvarchar

I'm trying to figure out how to modify a json stored inside a column of my table (SQL SERVER).

I want to remove a property of the JSON only if it matches with a specific string.

Imagine we have a record in our table with this JSON inside a column named "profile" (nvarchar(max)) :

```
{ 
  name: "goofy",
  class_cod_x: "1345",
}
```

Then another record presents this JSON:

```
{ 
  name: "donald",
  class_cod_y: "1457",
}
```

Now we want to search and update all the JSON inside our records that contains a property that **startsWith** "class_cod".

I want to remove all the "class_cod.." properties from that column.

I can imagine a query like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET profile = JSON_MODIFY( profile , "startsWith(class_cod)" , null)
```

Is this possible? In that case, which is the correct syntax?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Expected output:

```
{ 
  name: "goofy",
}
```

and

```
{ 
  name: "donald",
}
```

"class_cod" field completely removed.

**UPDATE 2**

- SQL SERVER VERSION: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)
- "name" and "class_cod.." are not the only possible field inside json column.
  That JSON is based on an enum of possible configurations.
- Is it possible that a JSON contains multiple "class_cod.." fields. (extremely rare but possible)

  ```
  {
    name: mario,
    class_cod_10: 22,
    class_cod_20: 31,
  }
  ```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I will update the answer with expected output

Comment: What is your SQl Server version? Are `name` and `class_cod_`? the only available keys in the JSON objects? Does every JSON object contain only one `class_cod_?` key? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov just updated with futher informations you needed, thanks in advance

Comment: OK, then a dynamic statement should be your first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can use wildcards for `path` parameter in `JSON_MODIFY()` and if the JSON in the `profile` column has more than one `class_cod_*` key, you may try to generate and execute a dynamic statement. The final statement includes one `UPDATE` statement for each distinct `class_cod_*` key in all JSON objects from all rows in the table. Note, that you need to use `lax` mode (it's the default) to specify that the property referenced by path does not have to exist:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (profile nvarchar(max));
-- Rows with one `class_cod_*` key
INSERT INTO Data (profile) VALUES (N'{"name":"goofy","class_cod_x":"1345"}')
INSERT INTO Data (profile) VALUES (N'{"name":"donald","class_cod_y":"1457"}')
-- Row without `class_cod_*` key
INSERT INTO Data (profile) VALUES (N'{"name":"tom"}')
-- Row with one `class_cod_*` key and other keys
INSERT INTO Data (profile) VALUES (N'{"name":"goofy","class_cod_x":"1345","age":10}')
-- Row with two `class_cod_*` keys
INSERT INTO Data (profile) VALUES (N'{"name":"jerry", "class_cod_x":"1345", "class_cod_y":"1345"}')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SELECT @stm = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
      CONCAT('UPDATE Data SET profile = JSON_MODIFY(profile, ''lax $."', t.[key], '"'', null)'),
      '; '
   )   
   FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
      FROM Data d
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.profile) j
      WHERE j.[key] LIKE N'class_cod_%' 
   ) t
   FOR XML PATH('')
)
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Result:

```
profile
{"name":"goofy"}
{"name":"donald"}
{"name":"tom"}
{"name":"goofy","age":10}
{"name":"jerry"}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot @Zhorov!!

In a similar case where the profile column is an array of JSON, Is it possible to apply this solution?

Comment: @Tommolo, yes, why not. You will need to use double `CROSS APPLY` to get the index of each JSON object in this JSON array, because the `path` will be like `$[0].class_cod_x`. But a test data is necessary or perhaps another question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create dynamic update statements and manually run the generated update query. Something like this.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET PROFILE=JSON_MODIFY(profile ,''$.' +x.[key]+ ''', null)'
FROM MYTABLE T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (profile, '$') x 
WHERE x.[key] LIKE '%class_cod%'
```

This query will create the list of update statements as below.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET PROFILE=JSON_MODIFY(profile ,'$.class_cod_x', null)
UPDATE MYTABLE SET PROFILE=JSON_MODIFY(profile ,'$.class_cod_y', null)
```

*Assumption: Each JSON record contains the key `class_cod_*` only once. Hope there are only limited rows where you can manually run the update statement*

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a2d906314e838201caa90ed6953735c)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arun, it works on json without multiple class_cod key.
As I stated in the updates, that case is possible but extremely rare.